# Jersey not able to serialize annotations?

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jersey, jackson

Serializing an annotation with jersey always fails with an unknown error.

Minimal example is:

**Jersey ressource**

```
@TestAnno( id = "TestID" )
@Path( "/test" )
public class TestResource
{
   @GET
   @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
   public TestAnno list() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
   {
      final TestAnno ta = getClass().getAnnotation( TestAnno.class );
      return ta;
   }
}
```

**Annotation**

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Target( ElementType.TYPE )
public @interface TestAnno
{
   @JsonProperty( "id" )
   String id();
}
```

The call always returns

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /schema. Reason:
Server Error
```

The debug log is empty, there are no exceptions or any other information about the error. What is the point where jersey fails?

Comment: Until the problem is solved, I've implemented a workaround. The method body of `list()` was changed to `ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); return mapper.writeStringValue(ta);`. This works for now.

Comment: Which Jackson version are you running? I'm not able to reproduce the problem on 2.4.1. I seem to remember that there were a bug in handling annotations in older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have Serializer with such a class. Consider to write your Dto class and map all the information from your annotation to it. Then just return in as a response.
Something like:

```
  public Response list() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
   {
      final TestAnno ta = getClass().getAnnotation( TestAnno.class );
      MyDto dto = buildDto(ta);

      return Response.ok(dto);
   }
```

Comment: Yes this would be an option, but jackson should be able to serialize those objects without a dto. If I do it manually via `ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); mapper.writeStringValue(ta);`, Jackson does serialize the annotation. So what is the difference between triggering Jackson direct, or letting Jersey trigger it.

Comment: I guess it's about some mapper settings, you could put breakpoint on serialization and see what's happen there and maybe overwrite this logic a bit. I can't remember the exactly class name now, on Sunday when I'll be at work PC I can try to find it out.